# pytest fixture finalization in the presence of errors

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have a test bench setup where I make heavy use of fixtures to provide resources and "items to test" to the tests I have defined. This is great, it allows my test functions to contain as little code as possible.

However I find myself fighting with pytest quite a lot in the area of finalization.

In pytest, fixture finalizers are conveniently described by making a generator of the form:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def a_fixture():
    #some setup code
    resource = setup_resource()

    yield resource

    #finalizer code here
    close_resource(resource)
```

Frequently, I find myself wishing that I could do this:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def a_fixture():
    #some setup code
    resource = setup_resource()

    try:
        yield resource
    except ValueError as e:
        #handle errors in finalization code
        handle_error(resource)

    #finalizer code here
    close_resource()
```

Some example usecases for this:

1. Many of my tests are testing functionality on a piece of hardware connected to a host PC. When an error occurs, I'd like the finalization code to collect more information from the device and log it.
2. In the event of a specific kind of error, I'd like to alter the finalization code that executes. For example, the tests have resulted in the device under test crashing and attempting to run the finalization code will just result in wasted time.

I raised a ticket with the pytest project about this, they informed me that this decision is by design and the best option for me would be to create a custom report hook.

I find the concept of fixtures to be extremely useful and powerful. I also find the inability of finalizer code to be informed of errors to be very limiting.  A custom report hook doesn't work for me because the finalizer code is too closely linked with its source fixture.

So now to the question:
If not propagating exceptions into fixtures is by design, how do you provide conditional resource finalization?

Comment: You could try to write a decorator for the related tests that does the exception handling and resource cleanup. The problem is of course that you may not have access to the resource at that point...

Comment: True, but that's outside of the fixture concept right? I'd lose the lovely scoping functionality. I'd also not be able to utilize it as a pytest fixture. Unless I'm not understanding you?

Comment: No, right - as you wrote, inside the fixture concept this is not possible (same for hooks). That would only be a workaround... I haven't checked the source code, but in principle you could write your own decorator derived from fixture (no idea if this is feasible).

Comment: Yeah it's a good idea, worth a look at least. I'll take a look at the source this evening and see there's any option there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just starting with `pytest` and ran into the need to finalize a fixture based on the test result too.

For reference, I think [this](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/7267) is the ticket you raised? I took some inspiration from [the response](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/7267#issuecomment-634577651) there and ended up with a fairly simple solution:

```py
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    """
    attach each test's TestReport to the test Item so fixtures can
    decide how to finalize based on the test result.

    fixtures can access the TestReport from the `request` fixture at
    `request.node.test_report`.
    """
    test_report = (yield).get_result()
    if test_report.when == "call":
        item.test_report = test_report
```

Now, in my fixture, I can inspect the report:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture(request):

    # setup ...

    yield

    if request.node.test_report.outcome == "passed":
        # passing-only finalization ...
```

The hook will affect all tests, but it should be a fairly benign addition.

I'm not using static type checking, but if you are, you might need to use `pytest`'s ["stash" feature](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/writing_hook_functions.html#storing-data-on-items-across-hook-functions) instead of assigning directly to the `item`/`node`.