# Different exit code with pytest when tests raise an unhandled exception (other than AssertionError)

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to know if a pytest test suite has failed because of:
1. a given test failed on an assertion, or
2. a given test raised an unhandled exception

So given the following tests:

```py
def test_ok():
    assert 0 == 0

def test_failed():
    assert 1 == 0

def test_different_exit_code():
    open('/nonexistent', 'r')
```

I want to differentiate (with different exit codes) between the `test_failed` and the `test_different_exit_code` case.

Comment: I don't think this is possible - the pytest runner collects and runs different tests, and the exit code reflects the overall result, not the result of a single test. A [somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62424582/pytest-fixture-finalization-in-the-presence-of-errors) has been asked recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally ended up with
https://pypi.org/project/pytest-unhandled-exception-exit-code/

This makes setting the exit code possible when an unhandled exception happens in any of the tests, like with the example command line:
`pytest --unhandled-exc-exit-code 13`

Answer (score 0):

pytest has a handled exceptions, let me show you one example:

```
import pytest
from pytest_bdd import given

    def pytest_bdd_step_error(request, feature, scenario, step, step_func, step_func_args, exception):
    print(f'Step failed: {step}')
```

This is a hook, you can use to handle errors in you pytest step_defs you only call in your  def test_failed() , so you can write this

```
def test_ok():
    assert 0 == 0 # Test is ok


def test_failed():
    #assert 1 == 0 # Test failed REMOVE THIS PART AND USE assert not
    assert not 1 == 0



def test_different_exit_code():
    open('/nonexistent', 'r')
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that def pytest_bdd_step_error() you have to put into a conftest.py file

Comment: if you want more information look this course chapter 9 https://testautomationu.applitools.com/behavior-driven-python-with-pytest-bdd/chapter9.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pytest-finer-verdicts](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-finer-verdicts/) plugin to differentiate between test failures and other failures (e.g., due to exceptions).

**Edit1:**
For example, in the below fragment,

```py
import pytest

def test_fail():
    assert 75 <= 70

def test_error():
    open("/nonexistent", 'r')
```

pytest-finer-verdicts will differentiate the following two tests fail due to different kinds of reasons.

```
collected 2 items                                                               

t.py FE                                                         [100%]

==================================== ERRORS =====================================
_________________________ ERROR at setup of test_error1 _________________________

    def test_error1():
>       open("/nonexistent", 'r')
E       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/nonexistent'

t.py:7: FileNotFoundError
=================================== FAILURES ====================================
___________________________________ test_fail ___________________________________

    def test_fail():
>       assert 75 <= 70
E       assert 75 <= 70

t.py:4: AssertionError
============================ short test summary info ============================
FAILED t.py::test_fail - assert 75 <= 70
ERROR t.py::test_error1 - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directo...
========================== 1 failed, 1 error in 0.19s ===========================
```

Comment: I fail to see how this can be used to set a different exit code

Comment: Since a process has only one exit code, what exit code do you expect when different kinds of test failures encountered in an execution of pytest?  I think one possibility is to differentiate the kinds of test failures in pytest's report, and pytest-finer-verdicts plugin does this; see the *Edit1* in my initial answer.

Comment: All my tests should get to the point when either they return successfully, or fail with an `AssertionError`. Apart from these, I would like to know if any other type of exceptions occur and it's the easiest to detect that with a different exit code.

Comment: So, you are asking for an exit code that signifies at least one test in the suite completed neither successfully nor with `AssertionError`.  I wonder if you can use/tweak [pytest-custom-exit-code](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-custom-exit-code/) plugin for your needs.